# Is there a better way to do this in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Im using handlebars to spit out some static pages using a partial like so:

```
{{> component/card size="small" title="Card Title" }}
```

Now depending on the "size" of the card required, i need to set some different tailwind classes. Im currently doing it like so, but there must be a better way? Adding the class to the container and writing css is not an option.

```
{{setVariable "additionalHeadingClass" "text-5 md:text-6 mb-4"}}
{{#ifEquals size "small"}}
    {{setVariable "additionalHeadingClass" "text-4 mb-1"}}
{{/ifEquals}}
{{#ifEquals size "large"}}
    {{setVariable "additionalHeadingClass" "text-4 sm:text-5 md:text-8 mb-4"}}
{{/ifEquals}}
<h3 class="text-primary font-bold {{@root.additionalHeadingClass}}">{{title}}</h3>
```

and heres the helper im using:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("setVariable", function (varName, varValue, options) {
    if (!options.data.root) {
        options.data.root = {};
    }
    options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that there is too much code in your template for what it actually does. Despite the intimidating number of lines, we really just want to map a `size` to a string of class names. I would also advise against the `setVariable` because I find it harder to think about when we creating a side-effect by manipulating a variable on our context object. I would much prefer a more functional-style helper, where we just give it the `size` and it returns the class names string.

I would create such a helper using a simple `switch`:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('additionalClasses', function(size) {
  switch (size) {
    case 'large':
      return 'text-4 sm:text-5 md:text-8 mb-4';
    case 'small':
      return 'text-4 mb-1';
    default:
      return 'text-5 md:text-6 mb-4';
  }
});
```

And then we may reduce our template to the much simpler:

```html
<h3 class="text-primary font-bold {{additionalClasses size}}">{{title}}</h3>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/06jozc4u/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks @76484 I like the solution, however because i need to do this a lot across a fair few templates and the back end team need to understand it clearly, i dont think this is an option.

Comment: Fair. I think what I would do in this case is just accept a little duplication for the sake of avoiding messy helpers. ie., `{{ifEquals size 'large'}}<h3 ...>{{title}}</h3>{{else ifEquals size 'small'}}<h3 ...>{{title}}</h3>{{else}}<h3 ...>{{title}}</h3>{{/ifEquals}}`